# Magento Custom Module: How to Create Admin menu

Tags: magento

```
Finder
Setting
```

what should be the url to go to system/configuration of our custom module from admin menu setting.

```
<menu>
 <finder module="finder">
  <title>finder</title>
    <sort_order>71</sort_order>               
      <children>
    <items module="finder">
    <title>Manage Finder</title>
    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
    <action>finder/adminhtml_finder</action>
   </items>
       <items module="finder">
    <title>Setting</title>
    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
    <action> ????  </action>
</items>
  </children>
    </finder>
    </menu>
```

Answer (score 2):

Jack you can give action like follow :

```
<action>adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/your menu item</action>
```

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/create-configuration-for-your-magento-extension/  this one is one of the good example.

Answer (score 1):

you can take as below to add in catalog of system configuration. and you have to create `system.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <helloconfig translate="label" module="todaydeal">
            <label>Today Deal</label>
            <sort_order>99999</sort_order>
        </helloconfig>
    </tabs> 
   <sections>
        <catalog>
            <groups>
                <todaydeal translate="label" module="todaydeal">
                    <label>Daily Deal</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>

                    <fields>
                        <active translate="label">
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </active>                        
                    </fields>
                </todaydeal>
            </groups>
        </catalog>
    </sections>
</config>
```

you can also refer Detail [Document LINK](http://www.pierrefay.com/add-config-field-magento-system-127),  i am sure i will very helpful to you.

let me know if i can help you further

Comment: yes that will create setting section in system/configuration but what will be the link to open it.   <items module="finder">
    <title>Setting</title>
    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
    <action> ????  </action>

Comment: you mean you want to call your custom module with your custom table data instead of core_config_data in system configuration ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code create admin side menu  and also have action to do system/configuration.Add following code in app/code/local/[Name_Space]/[Module_Name]/etc/config.xml

```
      <adminhtml>
         <menu>
            <news module="news">
                <title>News</title>
                <sort_order>71</sort_order>               
                <children>
                    <items module="news">
                        <title>Manage Items</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>news/adminhtml_news</action>
                    </items>
                    <items1 module="news">
                        <title>Import News Data</title>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <action>adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/news</action>
                    </items1>
                </children>
            </news>
        </menu>
  </adminhtml>
```

Note that here news will be the same as section name in system.xml file.

Comment: Excellent ... Helped me.. Short and smart... +1

Answer (score 1):

Hi  Add following code instead of `<itmes>`.

```
 <config module="finder">
                        <title>Configurations</title>
                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        <action>adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/finder</action>
                    </config>

              Write down ACL code after the </menu> ending tag.  Your code will be like this 

              <acl>
    <resources>
        <all>
            <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <My_module>
                    <title>My finder Module</title>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                </My_module>
                <system>
                    <children>
                    <config>
                        <children>
                        <finder>
                            <title>finder Module Section</title>
                        </finder>
                        </children>
                    </config>
                    </children>
                </system>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the link below to create admin menu in Magento2:
https://github.com/jainmegha5395/admin-menu

Explanation:

> You need to create menu.xml file inside \etc\adminhtml\ of your module.

Add below code inside `<menu>` tag.

```
  <add id="Custom_Module::custom" title="CUSTOM" translate="title" module="Custom_Module" sortOrder="90" dependsOnModule="Custom_Module" resource="Custom_Module::custom"/>

  <add id="Custom_Module::news" title="News" translate="title" module="Custom_Module" parent="Custom_Module::custom" sortOrder="50" dependsOnModule="Custom_Module" resource="Custom_Module::news"/>
```

This code will create a menu named as `NEWS` which comes under heading `CUSTOM`.