# On clicking a custom admin menu redirect the user to a php script in Magento root

Tags: magento, admin

I want to add a custom menu in the admin section on clicking which user should be redirected to a php code file which is in Magento root directory.

I want to run the script from magento admin.

[image]
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say you have file `muk.php` in your Mage root directory. You do not need to change `action` from your `adminhtml.xml`.

Instead in your module's controller, you can set redirect to your custom php script like below from `indexAction`.

```
public function indexAction() {

        $url = Mage::getBaseUrl().'muk.php';//your php file in root
        $this->_redirectUrl($url);
        return;
}
```

If you still face a `404 not found` error, then remove `index.php` from your URL.

```
http://example.com/index.php/muk.php   //may give 404 error

http://example.com/muk.php            //this will not give 404 error
```

Answer (score 1):

this is managed from adminhtml.xml of this your module where action tag will create url

```
<menu>
        <appointment module="appointment">
            <title>Appointment</title>
            <sort_order>72</sort_order>               
            <children>
                <items module="appointment">
                    <title>Manage Items</title>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                   <action>amit.php</action>
                </items>
            </children>
        </appointment>
    </menu>
```

Here `<action>amit.php</action>` direct to www.explt.com/amit.php

Comment: @Amit this is not working, redirect to  http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/amit.php/index/index

Answer (score 1):

What you could trying is

1. Create a regular menu see [Magento Custom Module: How to Create Admin menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481808/magento-custom-module-how-to-create-admin-menu)
2. Then in your controller action for that menu do a php redirect to the file